# Heroku Gem doesn't work after installing it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins, heroku

I am trying to get heroku running on Ubuntu 9.10

I typed

```
sudo gem install heroku
```

and everything works fine but then when I go to run:

```
heroku list
```

I get

> heroku: command not found

Comment: make sure your ruby bin directory is in your PATH. type "echo $PATH" and post the output if you need help.

Comment: the output of "gem env" would also be helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

run **gem enviroment** and look where is the **EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY** and add it to your **PATH**

In my case:

```
$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.5
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i486-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/1.8
     - /home/user/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org/

$ export PATH=$PATH:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
```

or add to **~/.bashrc**

Answer (score 1):

I was using RVM, and my problem turned out to be the following:

- I had installed heroku using 'sudo'
- I should have installed heroku as the current user, without 'sudo'

Found here: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/217493