# aptana studio sh.exe": gem: command not found

Tags: git, heroku, rubygems, aptana3

I am using aptana studio 3.
I am creating an app called `UBDTCE`.
I want run web deployment wizard an sign-in to my heroku account it asks whether to install heroku gem or not.
Then I get an error message:

```
$ gem install heroku && heroku create UBDTCE
sh.exe": gem: command not found
```

or

```
$ gem install heroku && heroku create UBDTCE; git push heroku master
sh.exe": gem: command not found
fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I am new to this git stuff, how would you troubleshoot those error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message `fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository`stems from the first error `gem: command not found`

As described in "[`-bash` is messed up?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3950640/6309)", you need to check your `PATH`, making also sure that `ruby` and `gem` are correctly installed (as in [this comment](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/439#issuecomment-7073122): `rvm install ruby-1.9.3; rvm use ruby-1.9.3`: it does include `rubygems`).